# Excel Web Query Show Full HTML Code

Tags: vba, excel, excel-web-query

Does anyone have a way that I can use a web query (or another automated VBA way) to import the full html code of a page into an excel page?

I need just about everything from `<body>` to `</body>` but don't mind if there is a solution that requires the full page import. I have had a good look online but can't come up with anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's 1 way to do it inside a VBA Macro. The `htmlText` object will contain all the HTML at the end of this sub.

Put a breakpoint before the `End Sub`, then add the `htmlText` object to **Watch Window** and you can then see all the data coming back in the **Watch Window** and decide how you want to extract the html data and where you want to put it in the Excel sheet etc.

```
Private Sub GetWebsiteHtml_Click()

    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    Dim htmlText As Object

    Set htmlText = CreateObject("htmlFile")

    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", "http://google.com", False
        .send
        htmlText.body.innerHTML = .responsetext
    End With

End Sub
```